# font-lock doesn't work on types

Tags: emacs, font-lock

I want every keyword with `_st` suffix to be highlighted with a different color.

```
(font-lock-add-keywords
 nil
 '(("\\<\\([a-z0-9_]+_st\\)\\>" 1 font-lock-warning-face)))
```

I tried with `prepend`, same results.

```
namespace base {
class some_container_st {     /* ✘ (default face) */
    some_container_st() {  }  /* ✔ */
};
}

typedef base::some_container_st some_container_st; /* ✘ */

int main()
{
    struct stat var_st;   /* ✔ */
    TStat abc_st();       /* ✔ */
    some_container_st a;  /* ✔ */
    base::some_container_st b;  /* ✘ */
    ...
}
```

Comment: You don't show the context. Hard to guess what else is going on. Font-lock keywords do not work in isolation - they work together.

Comment: @Drew added the context.

Comment: Sorry, I meant, especially, info about the value of `font-lock-keywords` after you add your entry to it. Each entry can affect the effect of subsequent entries. Dunno whether this will help someone to help you, but it's not necessarily easy to guess the effect of a font-lock entry in isolation.